# invalid syntax discrepancy, strange

Tags: python, syntax

I have written the following code  which defines a few functions that I will use later:

```
def dy1_dt(t, y1, y2, y3, y5, y6, i):
        S=pi*y5**2
        return -G*m_range[i]/y2**2+(1.0/(2.0*y3)*C_D*rho_range[i]*(y1**2+y2**2*y6**2)*cos(phi)*S


    def dy2_dt(t, y1, i):
        return y1        

    def dy3_dt(t, y1, y2, y5, y6, i):
        S=pi*y5**2
        return -0.5*C_H*rho_range[i]*(y1**2+y2**2*y6**2)**(1.50)*S/Q_abl

    def dy4_dt(t, y1, y2, y5, y6, i):
        return C_D*rho_range[i]/(2*iron_den)*(y1**2+y2**2*y6**2)/y5


    def dy5_dt(t, y1, y2, y3, y5, y6, i):
        S=pi*y5**2
        return -y5/(6.0*y3)*C_H*rho_range[i]*(y1**2+y2**2*y6**2)**(1.50)*S/Q_abl

    def dy6_dt(t, y1, y2, y3, y6, i):
        return -C_D*rho_range[i]/(2*y3*y2)*(y1**2+y2**2*y6**2)*sin(phi)*S-((y1*y6)/y2)

    def dy7_dt(t, y6, i):
        return y6
```

I am receiving an error message at the line of 'dy2_dt(t, y1, i)' which says 'invalid syntax'. I am at loss as to what invalid syntax is actually included therein--it seems all well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is indeed invalid, you forgot to close parenthesis.

If you expand your first function, it gives:

```
def dy1_dt(t, y1, y2, y3, y5, y6, i):
        S=pi*y5**2
        return (
                -G *
                m_range[i] /
                y2 **
                2 +
                (
                        1.0 /
                        (2.0 *y3 ) *
                        C_D *
                        rho_range[i] *
                        (
                                y1 **
                                2 +
                                y2 **
                                2 *
                                y6 **
                                2
                        ) *
                        cos(phi) *
                        S
```